# Customizable CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, client, customization

I would like to create a website that would allow the client to log in to an admin page which would allow them to customize their site, such as their site's background color etc. Is there is a way to permanently change the CSS of the UI of the website without directly accessing the CSS file? Essentially allowing a non-programmer to customize their own styles.

Comment: Yes. Look into using a back-end language like PHP to store the preference as a variable that is associated to a either a login session or user profile in a database. Then pipe the variable into the HTML output.

Comment: all you need you can do with wordpress. 0 code exp people can easily handle it.

Comment: check here: https://wordpress.com/

Comment: Was hoping to do so from scratch.

Comment: You could have a file with stylistic variables (using Sass), and allow your client to write to this file using a UI - you could then either compile the Sass server or client side generating the new CSS with your client's requirements

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a custom development, let's say you want to customize things like: font size, UI colors, page width, etc... the way to go would be something like:

- Having a UI (at the backend) for all customizable things... that way user doesn't have to touch code, just select things, like filling a form.
- With that information stored at the database, you will generate CSS styles accordingly, for instance, if you have a setting for "header background color" (with a nice color picker), you will generate a style like `#header { background-color: #000 }` (let's say that user selected black).
- You have here two options: putting all styles inside a `<style>` tag at the `<head>`, or using a separate stylesheet (which I'd recommend, for good practices sake), if you do a separate stylesheet, you'll have to write the file at the filesystem, and be sure of: custom stylesheet loads *after* the site stylesheet (or write all styles with greater [specificity](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/)).

That way you're not modifying permanently the site stylesheet, but adding an additional style layer which will override the default styling.

Now, if you want to go on deep waters, I'd recommend to work with [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)... you could set a *on-server* sass compiling environment, and, when user selects modifications, you just modify the variables on the sass, and re-generate the CSS which will be loaded at the site.

Hope this helps.